# Why doesn't a >>> 100 produce 0 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, bit-shift

So I was playing around with shifts in the console, and the results have me stumped.

Input:

```
a = -1
a >>> 100
```

Output:

```
268435455
```

I looked on the [Mozilla reference page about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators), but it mentions nothing about the behavior of >>> when you shift by large amounts. I assumed that shifting all the bits to the right with zero-fill would result in a zero.

Is this a bug in Firefox or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can only shift by a maximum of 31.

From the site you linked in your post ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)):

> Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the right,
>   discarding bits shifted off, and shifting in zeros from the left.

From the actual spec ([Page 77](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf))

> Let shiftCount be the result of masking out all but the least
>   significant 5 bits of rnum, that is, compute rnum & 0x1F.

What's actually happening is when you shift by 100 it shifts by `(100 & 0x1F)` or 4.

`-1 >>> 100 === -1 >>> 4`

If you were to split it up into multiple shifts then it will work:

`-1 >>> 25 >>> 25 >>> 25 >>> 25 === 0`

Comment: and the average implementation seems to do a X >>> (Y % 32). Hence in the example -1 >>> (100 % 32) => -1 >>> 4 = 268435455

Comment: Bitwise operators in JavaScript always treat their operand as a 32 bit  signed integer.

Comment: ^^^ more accurately a 32 bit signed big-endian integer, and that's why -1 ends up as all ones.

Comment: Now it's totally confusing... -1.

Comment: Thanks! That clears it up for me. I figured something similar to that might be going on, but you did me one better by providing a workaround and referencing the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Any [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) on a `Number` in JavaScript will convert its operand to a 32 bit big-endian signed number.

This means that if the number is larger than what can be stored by 32 bits, it will be truncated. [Big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) means that number are stored in *natural order* when reading it from left to right, i.e. more significant numbers are stored first, so if the number is stored over one byte, its first byte is the more significant.

This means that `-1`'s binary representation will be...

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

(This is `-1` in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). This is performed by calculating the number's value in binary, and then flipping each bit and adding one.)

When you shift by `100`, you will find it [only shifts by `4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19825510/31671), leaving you with...

```
00001111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

As you can see, the high bit is no longer set, so it's not negative, and it is in fact `268435455` (the number from your question).

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it's because my answer is wrong, I'd love to be given the opportunity to correct it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yours is correct as well, but I had to give the answer to david for being more complete (and since he needs the rep more than you).

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton Not a problem. Happy coding.